# How to update HighSlide content after AjaxCall without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a href link that is performing AJAX call and show the result in highslide popup.

```
<a href='/cgi_appsrv/designreq/newrequest.php?ajaxtask=show_popup_form' onclick=\"return hs.htmlExpand(this, {headingText: 'Select Design Location (division)', objectType: 'ajax'});\">Select</a>
```

Simplified version of PHP that returns AJAX response:

```
switch ($ajaxtask) {
    case 'show_popup_form':
    echo "111";
    break;
}
```

So, if I press on the link I will get a HighSlide popup with "111" inside.

Now I change PHP to this:

```
switch ($ajaxtask) {
    case 'show_popup_form':
    echo "222";
    break;
}
```

Now I do NOT refresh the page and press on the link => I get HighSlide popup with same content as last time: "111"

If I would use a simple AJAX call without HighSlide I would get the updated response - "222".

My question: how can I get the updated response from the server using HighSlide through AJAX call and without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to config:

```
hs.cacheAjax = false;
hs.forceAjaxReload = true;
```

Comment: The reason the language was removed is being discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221834/user-refusing-to-remove-unnecessary-and-possible-offensive-text-from-post), but this is not religious discrimination. I say this as a Christian myself. The reason that language was removed was that it was unnecessary to the point of the answer, in the same way that "thanks in advance" and other salutations are traditionally removed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts . It isn't offensive, just a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
preserveContent: false
```